# Display Zend_Form_Element_Radio on one line

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, radio-button

The radio buttons in Zend Framework are displayed in a column (one option per line). How can I remove the br tag from the markup so that all radio options stay in one line?

My decorators are:

```
private $radioDecorators = array(
    'Label',
    'ViewHelper',
    array(array('data' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'div', 'class' => 'radio')),
    array(array('row' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'li')),
);
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You need to call the setSeparator method on the Zend_Form_Element_Radio object, passing it ''.  Here's an example from [here](http://zendguru.wordpress.com/2009/03/05/zend-framework-form-working-with-radio-buttons/):

```
<?php     

class CustomForm extends Zend_Form
{
  public function init()
  {
    $this->setMethod('post');
    $this->setAction('user/process');
    $gender = new Zend_Form_Element_Radio('gender');
    $gender->setLabel('Gender:')
      ->addMultiOptions(array(
        'male' => 'Male',
        'female' => 'Female'
      ))
      ->setSeparator('');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

use options as follows

```
array("listsep" => ' ')
```

This will make radio seperation by ' '

Comment: the setSeparator function seems to doesn't take affect yours does. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use the Zend_Form_Element_Radio::setSeparator($separator) method:

e.g.

```
$element->setSeparator('');
```

The separator defaults to '\<\br />' as shown by getSeparator().