# how can set radio buttons horizontally in zend form

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, php

hi i am using zend form , i created a

> Zend_Form_Element_Radio element

that have two options

> yes , no

in my form it shows vartically ,one button below the other . i want to add them horizontally .

this is my radio button code

```
    $radio = new Zend_Form_Element_Radio('yes');
    $radio-> setLabel('Are you booking for someone else ?');
    $radio->addMultiOptions(array('yes','no'));
    $radio->setDecorators(array(
                                array('ViewHelper',
                                            array('helper' => 'formRadio')
                                ),
                                array('Label',
                                            array('class' => 'label')
                                ),
                             )
                        );
```

can i view them horizontally ?? please help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did a quick search, maybe this post will help?

[Display Zend_Form_Element_Radio on one line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1162107/display-zend-form-element-radio-on-one-line)

From the old answer:

> You need to call the setSeparator method on the Zend_Form_Element_Radio object, passing it ''.

Good luck!